# Python Searching for variable in file and appending another value

Tags: python

I'm making a quiz which requires to import the users name and score to the text file. I then check if the users score has already been submitted in the quiz so I can append the score to that name instead of creating a new set of data. This needs to be able to append THREE scores and then to remove the first score, second=first, third=second, score=third.

```
if classs == "1":
    text_file = open("Class1.txt", "r")
    data = text_file.read()
    text_file.close()
    if name in data:
        combdata = (name,score)
else:
    text_file = open("Class1.txt","a")
    text_file.write(str(name) +","+ str(score)+"\n")
    text_file.close()
```

Here is the code trying to search the file and append the score of the user to that name set.

```
liste = []
liste.append(data)
    for line in data:
        for name in line:
            liste.append(score)

print(liste)
break
```

However, the score is appended like this

```
['Dion,0\nJarrod,1\nJake Bing,6\nFat,0', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Try to use ConfigParser.

Comment: something is wrong with the intendation after the first `if`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you append something to a list it is added at the end of that list. So in your case you need to re-write your file in order to append the new score to the line you want. So I suppose you would need a function that searches for a certain name in the file and adds the new score in a new file:

```
def searchName(name, score):
    with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
        data = f.read().split('\n')
        with open(newFileName, 'w') as newFile:
            for line in data:
                if name in line:        
                    line+=(',') + str(score) + (',')
                newFile.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: Upon executing the function, searchName(name,score) I get this error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'line' referenced before assignment" for this line "if name in line:" in the function

Comment: You're right, the code was not completely correct. I have updated the answer, sorry about that!

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Can confirm this works. However when the second score is appended, if the quiz is done again the second score is replaced? Instead of a third being added. If this wasn't clear in my question, sorry. I'll update it now.

Comment: Upon appending a score to the user "Charlie". It'll remove any second scores from other users. For example if Jarrod had "0,2" - Charlies second score would be removed.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not really clear to me. However you could consider reading your scores from a text file and then keeping them in a dictionary having the name of the players as keys and the scores as values in a list: `scores = {"Jarrod": [0, 1], "Charlie": [1, 2]}`. This way you can remove the first score using the list.pop(0) method.